# beginWriteTransaction from multithreading

Tags: multithreading, realm

According to the documentation in beginWriteTransaction method

> Only one write transaction can be open at a time. Write transactions
>   cannot be nested, and trying to begin a write transaction on a
>   RLMRealm which is already in a write transaction will throw an
>   exception. Calls to beginWriteTransaction from RLMRealm instances in
>   other threads will block until the current write transaction
>   completes.

but when I looked at code I found next one:

```
void Realm::begin_transaction()
{
   check_read_write(this);
   verify_thread();

   if (is_in_transaction()) {
      throw InvalidTransactionException("The Realm is already in a write transaction");
   }

   // make sure we have a read transaction
    read_group();

    transaction::begin(*m_shared_group, m_binding_context.get());
}
```

Could you explain when a condition is met ?

> Calls to beginWriteTransaction from RLMRealm instances in other
>   threads will block until the current write transaction completes.

Answer (score 0):

The last call will lead to a method which will leave this intermediate cross-platform C++ API level and goes one level deeper into our internal storage engine, where it uses a mutex to coordinate exclusive access between processes and threads.
Once this mutex is acquired, it is hold until the write transaction is committed or cancelled.

Comment: Do you have some solution how can I resolve problem when I try to write from 2 threads to default realm?

Now I have only one solution:

1) `dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unique.name.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)`


2)and wrap all transactions in the blocks.